# Counting adjacency matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices

Here is a question that has come up in the context of a problem that involves counting partially ordered sets.

For an adjacency matrix $A$, let $p$ be the sum of elements in the strict upper triangle (upper triangle minus the diagonal) of $A$, and $q$ be the sum of elements in the strict upper triangle of $A^2$. For fixed values of $p$ and $q$, is it possible to compute the cardinality of the set of all such matrices $A$?

If yes, how does one go about it? My guess is that the problem may be easier to tackle if we demand that $A$ has some extra symmetry, but I have not been able to arrive at any definite conclusion. Though I am interested in the generic case (without any added symmetries), solutions for any special cases will also be helpful. So will be any references that deal with similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT (4/21/20): new link re: function inserted at end

---

Source: my tweets, with minor errors removed (https://twitter.com/krzhang/status/1252529588049072128)

Let's assume $A$ is symmetric and 0 on the diagonal. (disclaimer: I'm guessing this is not what you meant by "symmetry" because of poset context, but it may still be helpful) This means we are really working with unlooped undirected graphs, where
- p is how many edges the graph has, and 
- q is now many 2-paths (disregarding order) that are not loops.

Now, cool observation: 2-paths that are not loops can be identified with their middle point and 2 neighbors. So for each vertex $i$ of deg. $d_i$, it contributes $d_i(d_i-1)/2$ 2-paths that are not loops.

So our problem becomes: "How many ways are there to split $p$ into nonnegative integers $d_1 + ... + d_n,$ such that $\sum d_i(d_i - 1)/2 = q$?"

Some manipulation gives $\sum d_i^2 = 2q + p$, so this problem really reduces to
"Given the first and 2nd power sums of $d_1 ... d_n$, how many sets of nonnegative $d_n$ are there?" or the quite-beautiful probabilistic form:

"How many nonnegative integral distributions are there of a fixed mean and variance?"

There're number theory constraints here, so I guess this is hard (which means original problem is even harder). However, computationally this isn't bad. Here's a solution:

1. construct a 3-d infinite array so that $P[x][y][z]$ = "the number of ways to solve this with $x$ numbers such that their 1-power sum (sum) is $y$ and their 2-power sum is $z$
2. use *dynamic programming* to build this layer by layer by $x$. So compute everything with $x = 1$ first, then reduce each problem with $x+1$ to those with $x$ by summing over different values for the first element.

This gives an $O(n^2p(2q+p))$ algorithm.

Link (h/t Boris Alexeev): This last function is explored at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html as "sum of squares function." As I predicted, it seems number-theoretical and thus needs to be written as sums of modular functions for larger $n$ and $k$. Therefore, finding a closed form seems super hard.

Comment: Do you know of any references where the nature of the cardinality in the asymptotic limit of $n$ has been studied?